# In Stata, how can I only analyze observations with repeated measures using the mixed command?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset on multiple outcome for individuals in two groups that were treated (or not treated) by an intervention at two time points. However, not every individual has complete data for each measure at each time point.

| id | outcome | outcome_value | group | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | depression | 10 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | depression | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | depression | 10 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | depression | . | 2 | 2 |
| 1 | anxiety | 12 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | anxiety | 8 | 1 | 2 |
| 2 | anxiety | 12 | 2 | 1 |
| 2 | anxiety | 6 | 2 | 2 |

How do I exclude IDs that do not have an outcome in both periods? I only want to see how outcomes changed between groups over time for observations have data in all periods. I am using the mixed command in Stata to conduct this analysis.

Answer (score 2):

First drop the missing rows

```
keep if !missing(outcome_value)
```

Then, keep the ID/outcome combinations that have `_N==2`

```
bysort id outcome: keep if _N==2
```

Output:

```
    id      outcome   outco~ue   group   time   ct  
     1      anxiety          8       1      2    2  
     1      anxiety         12       1      1    2  
     1   depression         10       1      1    2  
     1   depression          8       1      2    2  
     2      anxiety          6       2      2    2  
     2      anxiety         12       2      1    2
```

As @NickCox has pointed out in the comments, while we cannot directly combine these two, there is still a one-line approach:

```
bysort id outcome (time) : keep if !missing(outcome_value[1], outcome_value[2])
```

Of note, we cannot do this:

```
bysort id outcome : keep if !missing(outcome_value) & _N==2
```

because `_N` is not reduced by group until after the rows with missing outcome have been removed.

Comment: This could be just ,`bysort id outcome (time) : keep if !missing(time[1], time[2], outcome[1], outcome[2])`

Comment: thanks @NickCox - see update, with slight edit to your suggestion

Comment: Thanks @NickCox, but this doesn't seem to work. Maybe I buried the lede here -- this data has two groups (1 and 2) in 3 time periods (1, 2, and 3), but data was only collected for group 1 in times 1 and 2, and for group 2 in times 2 and 3. I want to retain every ID that has a recorded outcome in group 1 for times 1 and 2, and in group 2 for times 2 and 3. Is that possible?

Comment: There was nothing in the question about 3 times, so my code takes your example too literally to work. Sorry about that. If you care to post a more realistic data example, then I will try to post an answer that copes with it. Please use `dataex` (read Stata tag wiki for more detail).

Comment: @statahelp22 ; yes, it is possible. However, you need to update your question with those details, and provide a sample dataset that illustrates the problem.; also, note that my original solution will work (as it doesn't refer to time periods).